# Select points within a country using google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, country

I have several markers plotted in a world map using google maps API.

I would like to click in a country and then delete all the other markers and only see the points within this country border. For example, if I click in Brazil I just wanna see the markers inside Brazil.

I also would like to get a list of lat-lngs of the points inside the country after clicking in the country.

Does anybody knows how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you got so far.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the most efficient way is, if you can, to add to all your markers the attribute of the country code where the marker belong to.

When a user click on the map, pass the given lat/long to Geoname webservice (for example, you can also use Google Geocoding API) to obtain the country code. Then loop over your marker array and keep all the desired markers.

To get lat long from a click and get the country code from Geoname:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ){
    getCountryCode(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng()); 
});

function getCountryCode(latitude, longitude) {
    $.getJSON('http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode', {
            lat: latitude,
            lng: longitude,
            type: 'JSON'
         }, function(result) {
            console.log(result.countryCode);
         }
}
```

If you're not able to append the country code to the markers attributes, you will have to work with polygons of each country and search that a point is in a polygon.
If so, maybe this extension could help you: https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon
And for polygons of each country, use a simple geometry like this one: https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries